# How to set focus to a textbox on page load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to set focus to the text box on page load event. I tried many solutions by referring the element id, but couldn't able to focus the element. Later when I inspect the element using firebug I found for the same element the id changes in different execution. I am looking for the simplest solution using javascript or jquery to achieve this

```
    <h:form id="form"> 
      <rich:dataTable value="#{books}" var="book">
        <ui:repeat value="#{authors}" var="author"> 
          <h:inputText value="#{author.name}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
      </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#form :input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
```

during document ready.

Comment: I used like this. Is this correct? Couldn't able to set focus to an element.
     <h:form id="form"> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form input:first').focus();
        });
        </script>
      <rich:dataTable value="#{books}" var="book">
        <ui:repeat value="#{authors}" var="author"> 
          <h:inputText value="#{author.name}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
      </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.selected').focus();
});
```

Should focus the input element with the class 'selected' on page load.

Comment: Where does the `selected` class come in? Am I just missing it?

Comment: not at all, since Kalpana asked for "the" textbox he made no statement that this is the first or the last one in his markup. So, I decided it's probably a good idea to involve a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub SetFocus(ByVal ctrl As Control)
' Define the JavaScript function for the specified control.
Dim focusScript As String = "<script language='javascript'>" & _
"document.getElementById('" + ctrl.ClientID & _
"').focus();</script>"

' Add the JavaScript code to the page.
Page.RegisterStartupScript("FocusScript", focusScript)
End Sub
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: Is that VB? How does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, this will grab the first input child of the `#form`:

```
$('#form input:eq(0)').focus();
```

Comment: I used like this inside the form, couldn't able to set focus

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form input:eq(0)').focus();
        });
        </script>

Comment: If you look in Firebug, is the script getting inserted? I assume you have the jQuery framework referenced somewhere. If so, where? It would need to be loaded before you can run any jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [whatwg.org](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control) the HTML5 autofocus attribute is only available in Opera at the moment but will be adopted by other browsers in the future.

```
<input type="text" autofocus />

<script>
    // jQuery
    $(function(){
        if(!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))){
            $("input[autofocus]:eq(0)").focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```